# Merge 2 Excel Files in R when lookup column for both files are text column and that are "similar" but not perfect match

Tags: r

New to R.
I have 2 excel files that I want to combine in R as one sheet. First excel file is called `Review_Data` and other one is called `Owner_Data` The only common column is called `Name` but the names are similar but do not perfectly match? Anyway I can combine these two files together easily? See image below.

Thank you so much in advance!

[image: image of 2 excel files with column names]

Comment: Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please just include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly.

Comment: The `stringdist` package can be used to calculate the distance between two strings (aptly named!), but you likely want `fuzzyjoin` for its `stringdist_left_join` or such.